# How do I drive a texture to translate with the X location of an object?

Tags: uv

[image]
[image]
I have a "conveyor belt" that *should* move proportionally with any object on top of it. I chose a lean way of constructing this belt - where only the texture moves, rather than a curve path etc. So I tried to drive the x location of the texture with the x location of the box. Unfortunately, the scale is touchy, and impossible to get right. The texture either translates too quickly or too slowly. Can you please suggest a workaround?

Download blend file here :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UvDZzcBzL5rWJVP6Xf5KGhcPcaxMcvQS/view?usp=share_link

Comment: There's a tutorial by CBailey about using a texture to produce an animated conveyor belt [here](https://youtu.be/ZMX-aQJbrpA?t=831) which might help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. He mentions @ 25:00 that he found the relation empirically. I want to know how the values relate. Note that I can get a direct relation if I do a very simple construct. UV unwrapping the belt seems to cause the issue.

Comment: Ok. It's a long time since I looked at that tutorial in detail but though it worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. As someone who builds conveyor belts in blender often, I am often stuck with this problem. Cheers John

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you manage to sort your problem.